# Decomposition speed of ozone

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, ozone, decomposition

> Elementary reactions of decomposition of ozone with chlorine are as follows (substance with $^*$ is reaction intermediate):
>   \begin{align}
> \ce{Cl2 + O3 &-> ClO^* + ClO2^*}\tag{1}\\
> \ce{ClO2^* + O3 &-> ClO3^* + O2}\tag{2}\\
> \ce{ClO3^* + O3 &-> ClO2^* + 2O2}\tag{3}\\
> \ce{2ClO3^* &-> Cl2 + 3O2}\tag{4}\\
> \ce{2ClO^* &-> Cl2 + O2}\tag{5}
> \end{align}
>   Calculate decomposition rate of ozone using steady-state approximation.

I have this physical chemistry homework, and tried to solve, but it was too complicated for me to do. Could anyone help me?

(I'm sorry, but I'm not good at English, so maybe my sentences are strange.)

Comment: Write down the rate laws for all steps. Set the intermediate concentrations to zero. Solve.

Comment: Show your calculation in the question. Describe what effort you have done in the question. Otherwise this question will treated as mere homework question and will be closed.

Comment: Isn't Cl radical a key factor in the chlorine catalyzed destruction of ozone?